# JavaScript - Drawing a circle/dot with each click depending on the coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates, mouseevent, drawing

I want to be able to paint or draw a circle/dot every time the user clicks inside a rectangle. It should be possible to add as many circles/dots as there are clicks and their position changes depending on the coordinates where the click was made. This is the code I'm using:

Circle:

```
 <circle cy="50" cx="50" r="30" fill="#f"></circle>
```

Code that I'm using: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_mouse_clientxy2

What should I add in this code so it does what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `<circle>` tag in an `<svg>` tag.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');

svg.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const { pageX, pageY, currentTarget } = e;
  const { left, top } = currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
  const { pageXOffset, pageYOffset } = window;
  const x = pageX - left - pageXOffset;
  const y = pageY - top - pageYOffset;
  const diameter = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  
  svg.innerHTML += createCircle({ x, y }, diameter);
});

function createCircle(center, diameter) {
    const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

    return `
    <circle
        cx="${center.x}"
      cy="${center.y}"
      r="${diameter/2}"
      fill="#${randomColor}"
    ></circle>
  `;
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
</div>
```

Also, changed the `clientX/Y` properties to consider the container, window offsets/coordinates for scroll compatibility.

Comment: Nice method! Is there any way to save each click's coordinates in an array? Sort of like `arrayDots=[{X: 23, Y:55}, {X:120, Y:78}]` I would like to print them in console.

Comment: @LeonHorka, yes, simply add that in the click handler.